# Why do the MOSFETs burn in my ZVS circuit?

Tags: zvs

I have made a zero voltage switching heater to melt metal components.

Here is the schematic (I found the schematic in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VK446fku58)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuDjR0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the real circuit:

[image]

I use two 12V batteries (in series) to supply the circuit. The problem is that every time I connect the probes of the circuit to the batteries, one MOSFET burns out ([030N10N datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/030N10N.html).) I have used MOSFETs in parallel because

1. I want to melt about 4-5kg metal and it needs more current, probably
2. I have many of these MOSFETs

What's the problem? How can I keep the circuit safe from burning out the components (especially MOSFETs?)

Edit1:

Here is a code of the Baxandall oscillator in [Circuit JS](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/) ([download the offline version](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/offline/))

```
$ 1 5.0E-6 4.43302224444953 44 5.0 50

c 560 256 560 320 0 1.0E-6 55.21909258338815

w 624 256 560 256 0

w 624 320 560 320 0

w 560 320 560 336 0

f 464 352 512 352 0 1.5

g 512 368 512 384 0

R 368 192 320 192 0 0 40.0 24.0 0.0 0.0 0.5

r 688 256 688 320 0 1000.0

169 688 320 624 320 0 0.083 2.0 0.02741325422103716 0.05907949881313025 0.09283520863006642

w 624 288 608 288 0

w 608 288 608 208 0

f 464 224 512 224 0 1.5

g 512 240 512 256 0

w 560 256 560 208 0

w 560 208 512 208 0

g 464 288 480 288 0

r 368 224 416 224 0 470.0

r 368 352 416 352 0 470.0

r 416 224 416 288 0 10000.0

r 416 288 416 352 0 10000.0

w 464 224 416 224 0

w 416 352 464 352 0

w 464 288 416 288 0

d 416 352 416 400 1 0.805904783

d 416 224 416 176 1 0.805904783

w 416 400 544 400 0

w 416 176 528 176 0

w 544 400 544 256 0

w 544 256 560 256 0

w 528 176 528 336 0

w 512 336 528 336 0

w 528 336 560 336 0

w 368 192 368 160 0

w 368 160 608 160 0

l 608 160 608 208 0 0.83 0.03375570981693621

w 368 192 368 224 0

w 368 224 368 352 0

z 464 288 464 224 1 0.805904783 12.0

z 464 288 464 352 1 0.805904783 12.0

o 0 64 0 35 139.98404638611277 0.3499601159652819 0 -1

o 7 64 0 35 69.99202319305638 0.04374501449566024 0 -1

o 20 64 0 35 18.707220957835556 0.046768052394588894 0 -1

o 11 64 0 35 80.0 0.2 1 -1

o 4 64 0 35 80.0 0.2 1 -1
```

And Here is the code of my circuit:

```
$ 1 0.000005 4.43302224444953 44 5 50 5e-11
c 560 256 560 320 0 0.000002 64.14826649910597 0.001
w 624 256 560 256 0
w 624 320 560 320 0
w 560 320 560 336 0
f 464 352 512 352 0 1.5 0.02
g 512 368 512 384 0 0
R 368 192 320 192 0 0 40 24 0 0 0.5
r 688 256 688 320 0 1000
169 688 320 624 320 0 2.0000000000000002e-7 2 0.03187469442309521 49.919907525535564 49.49858089600093 0.99
w 624 288 608 288 0
w 608 288 608 208 0
f 464 224 512 224 0 1.5 0.02
g 512 240 512 256 0 0
w 560 256 560 208 0
w 560 208 512 208 0
g 464 288 480 288 0 0
r 368 224 416 224 0 550
r 368 352 416 352 0 550
r 416 224 416 288 0 550
r 416 288 416 352 0 550
w 464 224 416 224 0
w 416 352 464 352 0
w 464 288 416 288 0
d 416 352 416 400 3 default
d 416 224 416 176 3 default
w 416 400 544 400 0
w 416 176 528 176 0
w 544 400 544 256 0
w 544 256 560 256 0
w 528 176 528 336 0
w 512 336 528 336 0
w 528 336 560 336 0
w 368 192 368 160 0
w 368 160 608 160 0
l 608 160 608 208 0 0.000039999999999999996 -0.42132662952630917 0
w 368 192 368 224 0
w 368 224 368 352 0
34 fwdrop\q0.805904783\szvoltage\q12 0 1.7143528192808883e-7 0 2 12 0
z 464 288 464 224 3 fwdrop\q0.805904783\szvoltage\q12
z 464 288 464 352 3 fwdrop\q0.805904783\szvoltage\q12
o 0 64 0 4099 69.99202319305638 179.17957937422435 0 2 0 3
o 7 64 0 4099 34.99601159652819 0.04374501449566024 0 2 7 3
o 20 64 0 4099 18.707220957835556 1.4965776766268446 0 2 20 3
o 11 64 0 4099 160 1.6 1 2 11 3
o 4 64 0 4099 160 1.6 1 2 4 3
```

It looks ok. A screenshot:

[image]

Edit2:

Just tried to use [LTSpice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) software to simulate my circuit. It was interesting. I got a 1kV spike on the gate of the MOSFETs! see:
[image]

Please note that I used RRE02 diode (max. Vr=600V) instead of BYC15-600 and [EDZV13B](https://www.rohm.com/products/diodes/zener-diodes/standard/edzv13b-product#productDetail) as zener diode.

The simulation shows that we have a problem and we need to remove that spike. I put a RRE02 in parallel with 40uF inductor and this is what I saw:

[image]

As we can see, the voltage of the spike was reduced. Again used a diode but didn't specify any specific part number and it looks the problem is solved! see:

[image]

Ok, **but what diode can tolerate such spike?** 1.5kV is too much high. Any idea?

Also here is the last schematic:

[image]

Comment: I haven't looked at the video but, the schematic, as I see it, simply turns on *all* the transistors. I see no switching or switched-mode related parts. So it looks like you're simply shorting out the battery to ground through `L1` and `L2`, in DC.

Comment: Just skimming through the video, at ~1:25 he says "generate pulses at 20 kHz". Are you doing that?

Comment: The video advertises a 2000W induction heater. With a supply of 24V, the current would need to be 83.3A. Eyeballing it, I doubt the claim of 2000W. Also, compare the amount of red-hot metal in the video with a 2000W space heater. Again, the 2000W claim seems very dubious to me.

Comment: Lack of individual gate resistors is a bad sign for starters.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I think it's called "Baxandall oscillator".

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I added a simulation code the you can see it. I don't have any oscop to see or capture the frequency.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I agree.

Comment: @winny I heared it several times. Why do they need individual gate resistors?

Comment: @Roh Look at your schematic and realize that you have no oscillator in there, and no switching -- only the gates of the switches connected to the power supply, thus keeping them on for as long as the supply is on. Check your simulation, it has uV worth of oscillations. And why add a transformer?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Another edit is added to the question.

Comment: @winny Another edit is added to the question.

Comment: Still lacking individual gate resistors. You can have severe oscillation between MOSFETs without them.

Comment: Is your L1/L2 wound on an iron powder core?

Comment: @Janka Iron powder or Ferrite?

Comment: I asked because this kind of oscillator requires an air gap in the core. So you either have to use an iron powder toroid core —those have a distributed air gap—, or a ferrite cup core with a definite air gap in the middle. It's unlikely that you have a ferrite core with a distributed air gap though they exist.

Comment: @Janka FWIW, the yellow colored core in the pictur is typical of #26 powdered iron. Usually the far side is white. Perhaps a pull from a computer PSU? Roh: If this can be confirmed, then the part can be looked up in e.g. Micrometals' catalog under toroids, match ID/OD/HT.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you. Picked it up from a labtop adaptor.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this circuit with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip).
Not really a good "schematic", ... if it does not start ...

- because of the center point on inductance,
- no control of power flow into the "load".

Coupling coefficients (between inductors) are not equal to one!
Coupling with "load" must be done with a one-half coil, not the whole inductor (?).
Added inductances // resistors coupled with "oscillator" to simulate "metal load".
Measured some voltages and currents, but not yet all completed about power.
Seems ok but ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you but, did you capture any spike? I added a diode in parallel to 40uF and placed a diode before this inductor in series. Now, I don't have any spike.

Comment: Sorry, no spike seen on gates.